# Refactor with loop

Tags: ruby

I have 2 snippets that need to be refactored

### First Block

```
if condition
  array.each do |a|
    ... # 1st block
    var1 = ClassA.new.methodA
    ... # 2nd block
  end
else
  array.each do |a|
    ... # 1st block
    var1 = ClassB.new.methodB
    ... # 2nd block
  end
```

I know that I can reduce this into

```
array.each do |a|
  ... # 1st block
  var1 = condition ? ClassA.new.methodA : ClassB.new.methodB
  ... # 2nd block
end
```

But this array is quite big (roughly 10,000), so it has to do the `condition` check many time with each element. Does anybody know the most elegant way to refactor this?

### Second Block

```
var1 = method1(array.first)
array.[1..-1].each #Loop from 2nd to last element
  var1 = var1 + method1(a)
end

ClassA(var1)
```

With this one I have to initialized the variable with the first array element as the parameter. (`method1` represents a long chain ActiveRecord scope)

These are minor but I am a beginner with Ruby, and I think it's better to inspect more way to have fun with Ruby.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please, ask questions about refactoring in a [Code Review network](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used it so much that I forgot about it. Should I delete this question?

Comment: It will be moved there by one of moderators. For the future questions, please post them directly there.

Comment: Please note that in its current state this would be closed as **off topic**  on Code Review because it is example code.

Comment: According to Code Review "Help Center", future questions like this should be asked to [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1

```
λ = condition ? ClassA.new.method(:methodA) : ClassB.new.method(:methodB)
array.each do |a|
  ... # 1st block
  var1 = λ.(a)
  ... # 2nd block
end
```

*Sidenote:* ternary operator is not worth such a refactoring; it’s impact on productivity is zero. Class instance creation, on the other hand, worth it.

#### 2

```
var1 = array.reduce { |memo, e| memo + method1(e) }
```

Comment: 1. I've updated the question. `methodA` and `methodB` use  array element as parameter, so that I can't do like this.

Comment: The second problem is actually different, but it will now link to another issue relate to my model. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the ClassName and the MethodName sorted out at the beginning then use the following inside the loop.

```
 "ClassName".constantize.new.send('MethodName', parameter)
```